# VPN connection "blocks" windows 7 computers in network neighbourhood

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn, network-shares, shared-folders

Using `Rasdial.exe` to make `VPN connection`, i am using `Windows 7`. When connection is active i am unable to browse Windows 7 or newer computers (ie. access shared drives). I get standard error message:

> "\xxx is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this
>   network resource. Contact the administrato of this server to find out if you have access permissions. The user could not be found.
>   if you"

I can still browse shared data on other Windows XP computers on same network. I can still ping all computers on network. What to do next to diagnose this? Remote computer is not used as default gateway. What else can help?

Comment: @Ramhound, questioner does mention he can ping local computers and that remote computer is not used as default gateway.

Comment: `The user could not be found` makes it sound very much as if this is a user conflict. It may be trying to use your VPN username to connect to the local Windows 7 machine.  Try an explicit `NET USE \\server\share /USER:mylocalname` from the commandline; does that work?